# Como ocultar a senha digitada (input) em um script .bat

Tags: input, script, login, bat

Eu fiz o seguinte script para acessar um menu de operações q é liberado apenas para os usuários permitidos q estão dentro do código:

Primeiro pergunta o nome de usuário e só pede para colocar a senha se reconhecer o usuário digitado, caso não reconheça, o código pede para colocar o usuário de novo e assim vai.
Porém o problema é q quando pede para colocar a senha, ela aparece nessa interface de login e qualquer um pode ver qual a senha quando é digitada.

Queria saber se tem alguma forma de ocultar ou mascarar essa entrada da senha só com bat, mas não entendo o suficiente para fazer isso

```
    @echo off
    
    title LOGIN
    chcp 1252 > nul
    setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    
    :: aqui são os usuarios e suas senhas
    set Usuario1=neymar
    set Senha1=0000
    set Usuario2=messi
    set Senha2=1111
    set Usuario3=gabigol
    set senha3=2222
    
    for /f %a in ('"prompt $H&for %b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%a"
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %b in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%a bebe"
    
    :Inicio
    title LOGIN
    mode con: cols=70 Lines=25 1> nul 2> nul
    color 0e
    cls
    set Opcao1=
    set Opcao2=
    echo.
    echo       FAVOR INFORME USUÁRIO PARA ACESSAR O MENU:
    echo.
    set /p "Opcao1=Usuario: "
    
    IF "%Opcao1%"=="%Usuario1%" goto :%Usuario1%
    IF "%Opcao1%"=="%Usuario2%" goto :%Usuario2%
    IF "%Opcao1%"=="%Usuario3%" goto :%Usuario3%
    color 02
    goto :UsuarioInvalido
    
    :neymar
    color 02
    echo USUÁRIO AUTENTICADO
    echo FAVOR DIGITE SUA SENHA
    set /p "Opcao2=Senha: "
    IF not "%Opcao2%"=="%Senha1%" goto :SenhaInvalida
    goto :MenuPrincipal

    :messi
    color 02
    echo USUÁRIO AUTENTICADO
    echo FAVOR DIGITE SUA SENHA
    set /p "Opcao2=Senha: "
    IF not "%Opcao2%"=="%Senha2%" goto :SenhaInvalida
    goto :MenuPrincipal

    :gabigol
    color 02
    echo USUÁRIO AUTENTICADO
    echo FAVOR DIGITE SUA SENHA
    set /p "Opcao2=Senha: "
    IF not "%Opcao2%"=="%Senha3%" goto :SenhaInvalida
    goto :MenuPrincipal
    
    :UsuarioInvalido
    color 4f
    echo.
    echo  USUÁRIO NÃO CADASTRADO NO SISTEMA
    echo  FAVOR INFORMAR UM USUÁRIO VÁLIDO
    echo.
    pause
    cls
    goto :Inicio
    
    :SenhaInvalida
    color 4f
    echo.
    echo   ATENÇÃO: SENHA INVÁLIDA!
    echo DIGITE NOVAMENTE SEU USUÁRIO
    echo     E INSIRA SUA SENHA
    echo.
    pause
    cls
    goto :Inicio
```

Answer (score -3):

Um exemplo usando powershell dentro do bat para fazer a senha aparecer como asterisco:

```
@echo off
    
    title LOGIN
    chcp 1252 > nul
    setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    
    :: aqui são os usuarios e suas senhas
    set Usuario1=neymar
    set Senha1=0000
    set Usuario2=messi
    set Senha2=1111
    set Usuario3=gabigol
    set senha3=2222
    
    :: for /f %a in ('"prompt $H&for %b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%a"
    :: for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %b in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%a bebe"
    
    :Inicio
    title LOGIN
    mode con: cols=70 Lines=25 1> nul 2> nul
    color 0e
    cls
    set Opcao1=
    set Opcao2=
    echo.
    echo       FAVOR INFORME USUÁRIO PARA ACESSAR O MENU:
    echo.
    set /p "Opcao1=Usuario: "
    
    set "ComandoPS=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Favor digite a senha' -AsSecureString; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword);[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
    IF "%Opcao1%"=="%Usuario1%" goto :%Usuario1%
    IF "%Opcao1%"=="%Usuario2%" goto :%Usuario2%
    IF "%Opcao1%"=="%Usuario3%" goto :%Usuario3%
    color 02
    goto :UsuarioInvalido
    
    :MenuPrincipal
    cls
    echo.
    echo Bem vindo "%Opcao1%" voce se logou com sucesso!
    echo.
    pause
    goto :Inicio

    :neymar
    color 02
    echo USUÁRIO AUTENTICADO
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`%ComandoPS%`) do set Opcao2=%%a
    IF not "%Opcao2%"=="%Senha1%" goto :SenhaInvalida
    goto :MenuPrincipal
    
    :messi
    color 02
    echo USUÁRIO AUTENTICADO
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`%ComandoPS%`) do set Opcao2=%%a
    IF not "%Opcao2%"=="%Senha2%" goto :SenhaInvalida
    goto :MenuPrincipal

    :gabigol
    color 02
    echo USUÁRIO AUTENTICADO
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`%ComandoPS%`) do set Opcao2=%%a
    IF not "%Opcao2%"=="%Senha3%" goto :SenhaInvalida
    goto :MenuPrincipal
    
    :UsuarioInvalido
    color 4f
    echo.
    echo  USUÁRIO NÃO CADASTRADO NO SISTEMA
    echo  FAVOR INFORMAR UM USUÁRIO VÁLIDO
    echo.
    pause
    cls
    goto :Inicio
    
    :SenhaInvalida
    color 4f
    echo.
    echo   ATENÇÃO: SENHA INVÁLIDA!
    echo DIGITE NOVAMENTE SEU USUÁRIO
    echo     E INSIRA SUA SENHA
    echo.
    pause
    cls
    goto :Inicio
```